# In Django how to retrieve substring till ocurrence of a dot, from a model, to show in a template

Tags: python, django, split, model

I have the following model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    news_text = models.TextField(null=True)
    ... # other fields
```

with the following view:

```
def news(r):
    news= News.objects
    values = {'news':news}
    return render(r,'webapp1/news.html',values)
```

I want to show in the template a substring for the column news_text, till the first 'dot' occurrence, like:

```
{{news.news_text| split('.')[0] }}
```

Tried this in template but got:

```
"invalid filter: 'split'".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has a limited set of [builtin template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/) and there is no `split` filter.

Also in Django templates you can access object's attributes or methods like `{{my_dict.keys}}`, but you can't pass any arguments. So you can't do things like `{{news.news_text.split('.')}}` as well.

All of this is done with intention to force you to separate logic from templates. So for your example probably will be better to define a special context variable and pass it into template's rendering context, like:

```py
def news(r):
    news = News.objects.all().get()  # don't forget to call some filters on object manager
    context = {
        'news': news,
        'headlines': news.news_text.split('.')[0],
    }
    return render(r, 'webapp1/news.html', context)
```

Also note that plural model names may be confusing: is it an array of news in each entry, or not?

Nevertheless you can create [custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) (and in many cases you should) to solve your problem.